# To retrieve data whose third character is '_' underscore?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find the data whose 3rd character is '_' underscore.

like this

```
Names
------
al_en
vi_i
sm_th
```

Comment: NO sir I tried with like operator it doesn't work ,and I am new to this Field ..So oly i asked ..If it is wrong means sorry@trent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do:

```
select name from t1 where SUBSTRING(name, 3 , 1) = '_'
```

[working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40045/5)

Comment: If any solution works perfectly for your question please mark the answer.

Comment: @viki Oracle _DONOT_ have `SUBSTRING()` it has to be `SUBSTR()`

Comment: yes sir..While saying we pronounce like that, I changed tat SUBSTRING() to SUBSTR()@OracleUser

Answer (score 2):

You can make use [LIKE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141) operator with [ESCAPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52148) clause.
Since '_' is a pattern-matching character, you need to use ESCAPE clause.

```
where names like '__\_%' escape '\';
```

Here first to underscores match any two characters, escape character '\' causes the third underscore to be interpreted literally.

```
SQL> with x(y) as (
        select 'al_en' from dual union all
        select 'a_en' from dual union all
        select 'awen' from dual union all
        select '___en' from dual union all
        select 'sm_' from dual
        )
select y from x
where y like '__\_%' escape '\';

Y
-----
al_en
___en
sm_
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COLUMNNAME
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE INSTR(COLUMNNAME,'_') = 3
```

[INSTR()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) returns the position of the specified string/character in a string.

Answer (score 0):

select name from table_name where instr(name,'_')=3;